# Chain problem and conservation of energy!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**PROBLEM:** A block of mass M is attached to a chain of uniform mass density, d. The system is initially lying on the smooth floor when the block is thrown upward with initial velocity v. Determine the maximum height reached by the block.

**MY DOUBT** I know it can be solved using Newton's second law with variable mass. But, can this problem be solved by conservation of mechanical energy?

Comment: Do you know the kinetic and potential energy at the start when the mass is still on the floor but has an initial upward velocity? Do you know the kinetic and potential energy when the mass reaches its maximum height? If so, you might well be able to use conservation of energy.

Comment: It’s easier used conservation of energy

Comment: Are you treating this as a chain rising vertically beneath the block, or is the chain infinitely long with an infinite total mass?  This would prohibit the chain from sliding and make this a 2-D problem for which you would need the shape of the chain as the mass curves through the air.  Will the chain be a straight line perpendicular to the motion of the block, or will the chain be curved?

Comment: It is a two dimensional problem where tension in the chain exists. So, conservation of energy requires using the hole system for cancelling tensions. But this makes the problem impossible because we can't see where is the center of mass of the chain.